# How can I embed a website link to a text in Expandable list-view?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

please take a look at the screen shot below and advice for example how i can make Afghanistan to open **www.google.com** when **Hope Academy Rwanda** is licked.[image]. I want www.google.com not to appear in the screen next to Hope Academy Rwanda. I want it on the background.

Comment: Why not setting the launch of the URL when clicking on the specific row of the ExpandableListView? Or you can put an onClickListener on the TextView itself. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29351281/2910520) on how to open an URL

Answer (score 0):

On Onclick  create Intent for individual link and get the url using its position put the web link in the form of URL object in place of url

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```